# Rosdep not fetching dependencies on RPi3 running Kinetic

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm building a package (create_autonomy) for connecting the iRobot Create2 to ROS. I have been having issues with the rosdep definitions for my system (a Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspian 9 with ROS Kinetic).

I have run rosdep update as well as rosdep resolve and am still struggling to resolve dependencies. For example, `rosdep resolve geometry` results in `ERROR: No definition of [geometry] for OS [debian]`. I have also tried this with geometry2 with the same result. I have similar errors when I run the catkin_make process.

So far, my only solution has been to manually add the sources for the required packages from github sources, however my understanding of rosdep as well as the package.xml file is that this should not be necessary.

I have noted that there have been legacy issues that appear similar to mine, although these claim to all have been resolved:

https://answers.ros.org/question/66750/rosdep-no-definition-for-os-debian/

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896413

Is there any way I can get past this issue, or is manually adding the dependencies my best approach?

Thank you for your help!

---

For completeness I have added the command trace and error messages:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy.git
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ca_driver: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
ca_tools: No definition of [joy_teleop] for OS [debian]
ca_description: No definition of [xacro] for OS [debian]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342641/rosdep-not-fetching-dependencies-on-rpi3-running-kinetic/) by [pgav](https://answers.ros.org/users/51268/pgav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not an answer as this won't fix your problem but will provide context on why it is failing.

ROS Kinetic doesn't have any binary packages for Debian Stretch (and you are using Raspbian 9 Stretch), this is why `rosdep` cannot resolve them.
There is no version of ROS providing packages for Raspbian 32bits so you need to either build ROS from source or use images built by someone.

Usually to get the sources of the missing packages to compile, I would use the tool [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator#A_set_of_packages_missing_from_the_current_environment).
Unfortunately in your case the `create_autonomy` package has not been released for Kinetic or any other distro so the tool cannot find it.

Edit:

Disclaimer:

- Hacky way to solve the problem
- Not tested for this issue, but I tried something similar on a
  RaspberryPi 2 running Raspbian 10 and
  ROS Melodic and it worked

The idea is to:

1. trick rosdep into giving us a list of `apt-get install ros-kinetic-...` commands for your dependencies
2. convert them into ROS package names `[...] apt-get install ros-kinetic-my-package` -> `my_package`
3. pass that list of packages to
   `rosinstall_generator` to get the
   list of repos to build from source
4. clone them
5. install any missing system
   dependency
6. build the ROS packages

Setup:

```
source <YOUR_ROS_INSTALLATION>/setup.bash
mkdir -p ~/create_autonomy_ws/src && cd ~/create_autonomy_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy 
mkdir -p ~/create_autonomy_dependencies_ws/src
cd ~/create_autonomy_ws/
```

(1) While Debian didnt seen any armhf packages, some other distros did e.g. Ubuntu Xenial. We will use `--os ubuntu:xenial` and also `--simulate` for rosdep to just give us the list of install commands.

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --os=ubuntu:xenial --simulate
```

We will keep only the lines with "ros-kinetic" in them and store them in a temporary file

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --os=ubuntu:xenial --simulate | grep ros-kinetic > rosdep_output
```

(2) convert `[...] apt-get install` ros-kinetic-my-package`to`my_package`

To convert we want to keep everything after `ros-kinetic-` (here my-package) and then convert `-` to `_`

```
sed -e 's#.*ros-kinetic-\(\)#\1#' rosdep_output | sed 's/-/_/g' > pkg_list
```

(3)

```
rosinstall_generator `cat pkg_list` --deps --tar --exclude RPP --rosdistro kinetic > ~/create_autonomy_dependencies_ws/deps_to_build.rosinstall
```

(4)

```
cd ~/create_autonomy_dependencies_ws/
wstool init -j4 src deps_to_build.rosinstall
```

(5)

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
```

(6)

```
catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF -j2
```

(7) source the resulting workspace

```
source ~/create_autonomy_dependencies_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
```

(8) build the create_autonomy workspace

```
cd ~/create_autonomy_ws/
catkin_make install
```

(9) delete temp files

```
rm ~/create_autonomy_dependencies_ws/deps_to_build.rosinstall ~/create_autonomy_ws/rosdep_output ~/create_autonomy_ws/pkg_list
```

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgav](https://answers.ros.org/users/51268/pgav/) on 2020-01-28**:
Thanks for this answer, I believe that it explains what is happening. Although it is unfortunate that the tools don't resolve the dependencies automatically, at least it is possible to resolve them manually by adding the sources to the workspace and building.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
You should be able to supply the `--os=debian:jessie` CLA (or any other version) and pretend you're actually running Jessie. There are rules for that version of the OS and provided the names of the packages haven't changed, it should still be able to install them.

For packages it can't find (ie: names have changed), you would still manually install them and then add them to the `--skip-keys` list (note: the *keys*, not the Debian pkg names).

**Comment by [pgav](https://answers.ros.org/users/51268/pgav/) on 2020-01-29**:
Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't have any different effect on things.

For completeness, the resulting error was the same as before:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --os=debian:jessie
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ca_driver: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
ca_tools: No definition of [joy_teleop] for OS [debian]
ca_description: No definition of [xacro] for OS [debian]
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-29**:
Just making sure: have you ran a `rosdep update` for the user you're trying to run `rosdep` with?

And can you also tell us how you've installed `rosdep`? You may be running into [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). Pay attention to the *Known Differences* section specifically (but read all of it).

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-01-29**:
As Debian Jessie 32 bits never had any ROS debs built (nor any other Debian distro) I believe it's normal that rosdep fails to find such packages.

But @gvdhoorn's suggestion is good because it gives a path to hack our way through it!
You could pretend to be an OS that has ROS Kinetic 32bits packages and use that to get the full list of missing ROS packages

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --os=ubuntu:xenial --simulate
```

Then you can use `rosinstall_generator` to get their source code and build them. I'll update my answer with steps on how to do so (it'll be a bit hacky though)